# Свойство величины размера

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно написать:

> частицы размером от 100 мкм и ВЫШЕ

или

> частицы размером от 100 мкм и БОЛЬШЕ

?

Речь о частицах, которые могут быть как 100 мкм, так и 110 мкм, 120 мкм и т.д..

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо *размером от 100 мкм,* либо *размером 100 мкм и выше,* либо *частицы размером 100 мкм и более крупные.*

Не может быть и **от**, и **сравнительная степень** одновременно. Это сейчас распространённая ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Здорово! Исправляем речь.

Comment: Рад был помочь, Арсений!)

Comment: *Не может быть и от, и сравнительная степень одновременно. Это сейчас распространённая ошибка.* — это **всегда** было настолько широко распространено в научно-технической литературе (я смотрю только самые лучшие издательства), что возникают сомнения в Ваших выводах.

Comment: А Вы считали, что так нормально?

Comment: Я и сейчас считаю, что это нормально. Воспринимаю как шаблон технического языка. (Случайно попал на эту страницу при поиске — движок не догадался тогда, что вопрос обращён ко мне и не просигнализировал :)

Comment: @grizzly: понятно, спасибо!